# TypeOrm + Sqlite works only in development [React Native + Expo]

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo, typeorm

On development the app database works very well but when I generated APK it just not work, I can't use the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answare of [jbenzshawel](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4561):

1º: `yarn add metro-minify-terser`

2º: Update the metro config to keep class names and file names. Add the following to the metro.config.js transformer:

```
minifierConfig: {
    ecma: 8,
    keep_classnames: true,
    keep_fnames: true,
    module: true,
    mangle: {
        module: true,
        keep_classnames: true,
        keep_fnames: true,
    },
 },
```

So if you need to create `metro.config.js` add the following:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

config.transformer.minifierPath = 'metro-minify-terser';
config.transformer.minifierConfig = {
    ecma: 8,
    keep_classnames: true,
    keep_fnames: true,
    module: true,
    mangle: {
        module: true,
        keep_classnames: true,
        keep_fnames: true,
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```